# CSS works only after inspect

Tags: css

I am experiencing an strange behaviour on my site: only after I inspect the page, the elements are displayed in the right place, otherwise I get a blank space between the last printed element and the bottom of the screen.

Link: http://reframe.thnk.org/tool/step/9/

This is how it should look:

[image: page after inspection]

And this is how it looks by default:

[image: default printed page]

I thought there were errors on the CSS or HTML code, but I already run the W3C validators without any errors in both.

Some HTML here:

```
<div id="wrap">
...
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="space32"></div>
<div id="sitemap">
...
</div>
```

Some CSS here:

```
.wrapper{
          font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.65em;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif',sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  max-width: 928px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    }
.clear{
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .space32{
        height: 32px;
    }
.siteWrapper {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.65em;
  font-family: 'Noto Serif',sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  max-width: 928px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 606px;
}
```

Comment: can we see the code?

Comment: Few lines of code is worth 1000 pictures

Comment: Javascript may be the culprit.

Comment: If you could either link to your site, or drop your code in a fiddle...that'd be great.

Comment: I don't think the code there will be too helpful to understand what's happening but I added just in case. I'm also going to add the link to the page (it is actually the page you get after finishing all the process of the app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `min-height: 100%` in step 9 and everything works fine :)

```
#mainWrap {
  /* min-height: 100%; */
}
```